# jQuery .has() & .click() function issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've made a long html code:

```
<div id="el">
    <p data-skip>Blablabla</p> // On click, toggle this, and toggle next p
    <p data-skip>Blablabla</p> // On click, toggle this, and toggle next p
    <p data-skip>Blablabla</p> // On click, toggle this, and toggle next p
    <p><span>1<span><span>2</span></p> // On SPAN click, toggle this p, and toggle next p
    <p data-skip>Blablabla</p>// On click, toggle this, and toggle next p
    <p><span>1<span><span>2</span></p>// On SPAN click, toggle this p, and toggle next p
</div>
```

Only the first p has display block, others have display none.

When I click on my div, if the visible p has data-skip attribut, then I wanna toggle it and toggle next. But if the visible p hasn't data-skip, then user must click on span to toggle visible p and toggle next p.

So I've made that code:

```
$('#el').has('p[data-skip]').click(function() {
    var visible = $('#el p:visible');
    visible.toggle();
    $('#el p).eq(visible.index() + 1).toggle();
});
```

It work fine and if I change p[data-skip] by p[data-test] for example, it stop working.

But, when p hasn't data-skip attribut but only span, I still can click on it -_-

So, if I switch .has('p[data-blablabla']) the click() function stop working, but if the element hasn't the attribut, it work...

Can you explain me my error ?

Please don't tell me replace data-skip by class="skip" for using .hasClass(), it will working but I wanna use data- :)

Comment: You're attaching the event handler to the `#el` element, and all the clicks on any element inside it will bubble up to that point.

Comment: So why with .has('p[data-test']) I cannot click if the p has data-skip, but I can click if the p hasn't data attribut ?

Comment: @Delboar Nice way of replying to someone trying to help dude (edit: guess that comment got deleted). Pretty sure he did read your post, you probably didn't read or understand his comment however. Your event will fire **on `#el`** if **any** paragraph inside of it has the `data-skip` attribute. Same for `data-anything`.

Answer (score 0):

You would probably be better off listening on the `<p>` elements and checking the target when the `<p>` doesn't have a `data-skip`

```js
var $para = $('#el p').click(function(e){
   var $p = $(this);
   var $next = $p.is($para.last()) ? $p.next() : $para.first();
   
   // do nothing if not a `data-skip` and span not clicked
   if(!$p.is('[data-skip]') && !$(e.target).is('span')){
      return; 
   }else{
      $p.add($next).toggle()
   }       
});
```

```css
#el p:not(:first-child){display:none}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="el">
    <p data-skip>First</p> 
    <p data-skip>Second</p>
    <p data-skip>Third</p>
    <p><span>1<span><span>2</span></p>
    <p data-skip>Forth</p>
    <p><span>3<span><span>4</span></p>
</div>
```